# Is a BigInteger a CTS supported type (.NET)?

Tags: c#, .net

I was reading about `BigInteger`s (numeric types in C# that "scale up". Useful for example when doing a *Fibonacci sequence* where numbers quickly get *too big* for a `long`).

Now, I am wondering whether the `CTS` supports the `BigInteger`. E.g., can I use the `BigInteger` type in *all* .NET languages?

Comment: This doc page shows C#, C++, F#, and VB: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx -- since it is a framework feature and not a language-specific keyword (e.g.), it should be available to all languages that can use that version of the framework.

Comment: I don't see why not, since it is just a struct defined in `System.Numerics`. It uses an `uint[]` array behind the scenes.

Comment: Can you please clarify what "CTS" mean for you (maybe "[Common Type System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcx1eb1e(v=vs.110).aspx) - but question sounds strange than as whether `BigInteger` is type defined in .Net)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not carry out an *experiment* and see?

```
  uisng System.Linq;
  using System.Numerics;
  uisng System.Reflection;
  ...

  var result = typeof(BigInteger)
    .Assembly
    .GetCustomAttributes()
    .Select(attr => attr.GetType().Name)
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
AssemblySignatureKeyAttribute
DebuggableAttribute
ComVisibleAttribute
CLSCompliantAttribute                    <--------------- that is!
AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute
SecurityRulesAttribute
AssemblyTitleAttribute
AssemblyDescriptionAttribute
AssemblyDefaultAliasAttribute
AssemblyCompanyAttribute
AssemblyProductAttribute
AssemblyCopyrightAttribute
AssemblyFileVersionAttribute
AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute
SatelliteContractVersionAttribute
NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute
AssemblyDelaySignAttribute
AssemblyKeyFileAttribute
CompilationRelaxationsAttribute
RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute
SecurityPermissionAttribute
```

As you can see, `BigInteger` struct is implemented in the assembly which explictly declares `CLSCompliantAttribute`. That's why the answer is "**Yes**, `BigInteger` is *CLS compliant* and can be used in *any* .Net language".

See

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.clscompliantattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

for details

**Edit**: Some `BigInteger` members, however, are **not** CLSCompliant (see  Tim Schmelter's comments):

```
 var result = typeof(BigInteger)
    .GetMembers(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(member => member
       .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CLSCompliantAttribute))
       .OfType<CLSCompliantAttribute>()
       .Any(attr => !attr.IsCompliant))
    .Select(member => $"{member.Name}")
    .ToArray();
```

Outcome:

```
Equals                     Equals(UInt64 other)     
CompareTo                  CompareTo(UInt64 other)  
op_Implicit                operator
op_Implicit                -/- 
op_Implicit                -/-
op_Implicit                -/-
op_Explicit                -/-  
op_Explicit                -/-
op_Explicit                -/- 
op_Explicit                -/-  
op_LessThan                -/-
op_LessThanOrEqual         -/-   
op_GreaterThan             -/-
op_GreaterThanOrEqual      -/-  
op_Equality                -/-
op_Inequality              -/-
op_LessThan                -/-  
op_LessThanOrEqual         -/-   
op_GreaterThan             -/-
op_GreaterThanOrEqual      -/-  
op_Equality                -/- 
op_Inequality              -/-
.ctor                   BigInteger(uint value)
.ctor                   BigInteger(UInt64 value)
.ctor                   BigInteger(Byte[] value)
```

Comment: I see, all members that are not cls-compliant are marked with `[CLSCompliant(false)]` like [`Equals`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs,c3973fd56a49c827,references)(because of `uint` parameter). That makes it cls-compliant per [definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx).

Comment: Note that question does not ask about CSL compliance at from what I can see... So while correct I'm not sure this actually answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the MSDN documentation for [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx), you have examples in `C#`, `C++`, `VB.NET` and `F#` (all supported CLI languages).

Types available only to `C#` are normally defined under the `Microsoft.CSharp` namespace:

> The `Microsoft.CSharp` namespaces contain types that support compilation and code generation of source code written in the `C#` language, and types that support interoperation betwen the dynamic language runtime (DLR) and `C#`.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN page states

> **Universal Windows Platform**
>   Available since 8
>   **.NET Framework**
>   Available since 4.0
>   **Portable Class Library**
>   Supported in: portable .NET platforms
>   **Silverlight**
>   Available since 4.0
>   **Windows Phone**
> Available since 8.1

So the answer is ***yes***